# Robust formula to get row,column of raster given X,Y

Tags: raster, gis-principle, floating-point

I'm looking for a robust method to get the row and column of a pixel in a raster, given the coordinates of the origin and the cell spacing. This seems like a problem with an incredibly obvious solution, which I've tried implementing (for a column):

```
x0 = 8.5
dx = 0.1

function col(x) {
  return (int) ((x - x0) / dx)
}
```

However, this method frequently gives an incorrect column number because of floating point arithmetic issues. For example, with the origin coordinate and spacing shown above, the `x` values of `16.1` and `16.2` both return a column number of `76`. In reality, the the `x` value of `16.2` should be in column `77`.

Here is another example, using the `raster` package in `R` (which applies the same formula as above):

```
r <- raster(xmn=8.5, ymn=1.6, xmx=16.4, ymx=13.1, res=c(0.1, 0.1))
colFromX(r, seq(8.5, 9.5, 0.1))
```

This outputs the following:

```
1  1  2  4  5  6  6  7  9 10 11
```

This is wrong 40% of the time! So, the question: is there a robust formula to find a row/column number?

Comment: I do this calculation all the time and I've never had a problem with this. But I use Python. Is there a "round" function you could use instead of "int"?

Comment: @Jon this fails in Python too, and I assume in any IEEE floating point implementation. You can try it: `import math; math.floor((16.1-8.5)/0.1); math.floor((16.2-8.5)/0.1)`

Comment: Why not round((16.2-8.5)/0.1) ?

Comment: If a cell is defined as being from 8.5 to 8.6, then the value 8.56 is in the cell starting at 8.5, not the cell starting at 8.6.

Comment: Ah, duh. It's an interesting question, because I just looked through my functions that do this transformation and I use the same formula you show, but I have never seen unexpected behavior. And I check thousands upon thousands of such conversions as I often move from Python lists/numpy arrays to shapefiles for inspection in QGIS.

Comment: Also, one possibility is to use round with a tolerance in the subtraction term, like round((16.2-8.5), 5)/0.1

Comment: bit late, dirty hack, almost too obvious to post; I simply multiply all terms by the decimal magnitude (lacking the english words here, you know, `0.1 * 10`). drawback: a) lame, b) you need to know the decimal places that matters and floor them accordingly. works in python with `int`